# CUDA Visual Studio 2017 integration for nvidia Fermi GPU system

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2017

I recently noticed that in CUDA9 RC release notes is saying that CUDA 9 does not support Fermi GPUs.[CUDA 9 RC release link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-release-candidate-download)

Therefore how can we integrate earlier CUDA setups with Visual studio 2017 for fermi GPUs?

(I have Geforce 540m GT GPU, also CUDA 8 cannot be integrated with Visual Studio 2017.)

How can we integrate CUDA 9 or CUDA 8 with Visual Studion 2017? any solution or alternative? please help.

Please refer here too :- [nvidia Developer Forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1021226/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-visual-studio-2017-integration-for-nvidia-fermi-gpu-system/)

Comment: There is no supported toolchain from NVIDIA that combines support for Fermi GPUs with support for VS 2017

Answer (score 3):

> Therefore how can we integrate earlier CUDA setups with Visual studio
>   2017 for fermi GPUs?

You can't.

> How can we integrate CUDA 9 or CUDA 8 with Visual Studion 2017? any
>   solution or alternative?

CUDA 9 (when released) will have VS2017 integration support, earlier versions do not and this will not change. If you need  to support a now deprecated Fermi GPU, you will have to use an earlier toolkit and a supported VS version.

Comment: thank you for the information.so can we conclude that  for the fermi CUDA 9  with VS2017 unavailable  and not possible ?

Comment: CUDA 9 will not support Fermi, with or without VS 2017, or VS 2015 or any other VS or on linux.  **CUDA 9 does not support Fermi**.  The notification of this was given with CUDA 8, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382987/nvcc-warning-in-cuda-8-0/42383065#42383065).